# Can I take a jack if I'm at the hand limit?

Tags: glory-to-rome

When at the hand limit, I can always draw one card. Does this include a jack, or can I only draw a face down card from the deck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Hand limit" is a soft limit.

You can take a card when at or above the hand limit. Including a Jack.